# Google Bigquery API: How to get the name of temporary table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, temp-tables

I know that: The result of query will save in a temporary table. But how to get its name to use in other query.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

def test():
    project_id = "598330041668"
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
    # [START run_query]
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {
        'query': (
            'SELECT * '
            'FROM [test.names];')
    }

    query_response = query_request.query(
        projectId=project_id,
        body=query_data).execute()
    # [END run_query]
```

Comment: paste your code...

Comment: Hi @SmitaAhinave, I added code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the job ID of the query you ran.  This is present in the response from `jobs.query` in the [`jobReference`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#jobReference) field.
2. Look up the query configuration for the job you ran using the [`jobs.get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) method.  Inspect the field [`configuration.query.destinationTable`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable).

However, note that if you didn't specify your own destination table, that BigQuery assigns [a temporary one that should only be used in certain APIs, which does **not include other queries**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query):

> The query results from this method are saved to a temporary table that is deleted approximately 24 hours after the query is run. You can read this results table by calling either bigquery.tabledata.list(table_id) or bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults(job_reference). **The table and dataset name are non-standard, and cannot be used in any other other APIs**, as the behavior may be unpredictable.

If you want to use the results of a query in a subsequent query, I suggest setting the `configuration.query.destinationTable` yourself to write to a table of your choice.

Comment: yeah. Thanks a lot of.